# How to iterate over an object containing rows to insert in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm new in meteor and mongodb and I'm developping a web application to upload images to the server. Many rows can be stored in the mongodb database using the following code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
Uploader.finished = function(index, file) {
Uploads.insert(file);
});
```

so each row corresponding information about an image: id, name, path, url...
I want before the insertion iteration over file to take just what I need, and to add some other information for each row.
When I made console.log(file) to see the rows I got the following result:

```
Object {name: "T_12_11_2015_31.007565_3_-6.874119 (38).jpg", path: "/T_12_11_2015_31.007565_3_-6.874119 (38).jpg", size: 76628, type: "image/jpeg", error: null…}
Object {name: "T_12_11_2015_31.019565_11_-6.773020 (17).jpg", path: "/T_12_11_2015_31.019565_11_-6.773020 (17).jpg", size: 58596, type: "image/jpeg", error: null…}
Object {name: "T_12_11_2015_31.015365_13_-6.873018 (18).jpg", path: "/T_12_11_2015_31.015365_13_-6.873018 (18).jpg", size: 207715, type: "image/jpeg", error: null…}
```

I hope I'm clear. thank you in advance

Comment: _"I want before the insertion iteration over file to take just what I need, and to add some other information for each row."_ What is "just what I need"? And what information do you want to add?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You want to know how to loop over the array?

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain more, this line "Uploads.insert(file);" insert many rows to the database mongodb. So I want, using the savascript and before doing the insertion, take each row from "file" (rows mentioned above). And to save row by row rather than the all "file". because I want to make some changes in each row. did you get the point?

Comment: for example I tried to do like that : 
    file.forEach(function (f) {
console.log(f);
    }); but it gives me this error : file.forEach is not a function

Comment: when you say you made 'console.log(file);` do you mean you had a console.log(file) in the function? And you're uploading 3 files? 
It sounds to me it's just your function that is being ran 3 times and you have a 'file' object each time. So it's not that you have multiple rows in this file object, you have 1 file object per run of the function. Therefore all you have to do is use `del keyname` to remove a key you don't want and `file['key_to_add'] = 'my info' `to add a key

Comment: Oooh perfect thank you so much you are right :). I did what you said and it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by MrE and this is his solution :

"when you say you made 'console.log(file);` do you mean you had a console.log(file) in the function? And you're uploading 3 files? It sounds to me it's just your function that is being ran 3 times and you have a 'file' object each time. So it's not that you have multiple rows in this file object, you have 1 file object per run of the function. Therefore all you have to do is use del keyname to remove a key you don't want and file['key_to_add'] = 'my info' to add a key"